# Django filter models with a list of related items

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

For a simple Book model with a related Tag table, I'd like to filter out Books that have a list of tags:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.Textfield()

class Tag(models.Model):
    value = models.Textfield()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tags")
```

If I want to search all Books that have a both a "red" Tag and a "blue" tag, I can't simply run:

```
Book.objects.filter(Q(tags__value="red") & Q(tags__value="blue"))
```

because that tries to find an impossible Tag that has both the value "blue" and "red". Note that OR-ing the conditions is not correct either since I'm looking for Books that have both a "red" and a "blue" tag; a Book with just one or the other should not be returned.

Comment: Applying filter twice should do the work for you `Book.objects.filter(tags__value='red').filter(tags__value='blue')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's meant to get the ids of books that have either tag, check which ids are in both lists, and finally query for the books you need.

```
Book.objects.filter(
    pk__in=(
        Book.objects.filter(tags__value="red").values_list('pk', flat=True) 
        & Book.objects.filter(tags__value="blue").values_list('pk', flat=True)
    ),
)
```